# How can I solve this animation

Tags: xna, textures, animation, monogame

At the moment I have a simple static texture. Now I want to animate my sprite. The texture is a simple human. When the user press the enter button, the human gets into state2. This is the standart state during gameplay. If the user presses now "space" the sprite should get into state4(4th texture). This would be very unsmooth, so I decided to make a State3(ist just displayed very short to make the animation smooth). Now the sprite is in state4. If the user now releas the "space"-key the sprite should return into State2. For smoothness there is State3 short between.

**State1** "*press enter*" --> **State2** --- "*press space*" --> (short **State3** for smoothness) --> **State4** --> "*release space*" --> (short **State3**) --> **State2**

I hope you understand what I mean :)

michi

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at the official MSDN tutorial that covers animations, among other things: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started

Comment: There you see just like on all the other sites who you can make a always repeating linear animation.

Comment: I recommend you look through the code and try to understand it. In the animation class, there is a "bool Looping". Unsurprisingly, it determines whether the animation will loop or not. Simply always set it to false and leave it there to get exactly one run. Add another "bool Reverse" that causes to play the animation in reverse. When the user presses space, set active to true. When the user releases the space bar, set reverse to true, play the animation in reverse, then set active to false when the animation is done.

Comment: Ok. I understand what you mean. What is your question?

Comment: Please edit your old question with the additional details, don't start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class that you can reuse if you do it right, you can for example set a counter that counts down whenever the player is moving and create an animation from a "[Sprite Strip](http://www.google.se/search?hl=sv&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=955&q=sprite%20strip&oq=sprite%20strip&gs_l=img.3..0i19.743.2240.0.2428.12.9.0.3.3.0.135.692.6j3.9.0...0.0...1ac.1.2.img.Ma2-2je3dR8)"

```
public class SpriteAnimation : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DrawableGameComponent
{
    int Rows, CurrentRow, Columns, CurrentColumn, X, Y, Width, Height;
    Texture2D Texture;
    SpriteBatch SpriteBatch;
    Rectangle destRectangle, sourceRectangle;

    public SpriteAnimation(int rows, int columns, Texture2D texture, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Game game)  : base(game)
    {
        this.Rows = rows;
        this.Columns = columns;
        this.SpriteBatch = spriteBatch;
        this.Texture = texture;
        this.Width = this.Texture.Width / this.Columns;
        this.Height = this.Texture.Height / this.Rows;

        SetPosition(0, 0);
        SetFrame(0, 0);
    }

    public void SetPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;

        destRectangle = new Rectangle(X, Y, Width, Height);
    }

    public void SetFrame(int row, int column)
    {
        if (row >= 0 && row <= (Rows - 1))
        {
            CurrentRow = row;
        }

        if (column >= 0 && column <= (Columns - 1))
        {
            CurrentColumn = column;
        }

        sourceRectangle = new Rectangle((CurrentColumn * Width), (CurrentRow * Height), Width, Height);
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);

        KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) { /* SetFrame(0, 1) */ }
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);

        SpriteBatch.Begin();
        SpriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White);
        SpriteBatch.End();

    }
}
```

If you check the link above that I include "Sprite Strip", you see that they're divided into columns and rows and that's what you use them for. For your animation, create a texture that has all four states and then you can jump between them whenever you need. So if you have all the different state textures on one row, then row = 1, columns = 4. Then you can extend this class to make it handle an animation yourself.